Sending a Mesibo message with a image using the backend API
I used the following rest call:
{
"op": "message",
"token": "my token",
"message": {
    "from": "from address",
    "to": "to address",
    "gid": 0,
    "type": 0,
    "expiry": 3600,
    "flags": null,
    "forced": true,
    "message": "Message with preview and other stuff.  Longer lines 22222/show preveiw",
    "url" : "image URL of image.  I can view in chrome"
}

}
The message goes through and shows a empty image that I cannot click on.  How would I send images from my backend java application that can be displayed on the demo app.
Thank you
I tried using the url  option.  Expected to see the image on the demo app.

Please remove flags=null from the payload.
Also, try the following. Change to, from, and token as appropriate
{
    "to": "to address",
    "from": "from address",
    "message": "Hello from the backend",
    "type": 0,
    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Astilbe_japonica_%27Red_Sentinel%27.jpg/800px-Astilbe_japonica_%27Red_Sentinel%27.jpg"
}

The curl command for quick testing
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request POST \
     --data '{"op": "message", "token": "token", "message": {"to": "to address", "from": "from address", "message": "Hello from backend", "type": 0, "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Astilbe_japonica_%27Red_Sentinel%27.jpg/800px-Astilbe_japonica_%27Red_Sentinel%27.jpg" }}' \
     https://api.mesibo.com/backend


Works, thanks so much.

Glad we could help. Please mark the answer as accepted.
